# GMailApp Gmail search

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail

I have a problem with the [GmailApp search(query) function](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#search(String)).

According to the manual it uses [Gmail queries](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7190?hl=en), so all the arguments should be accessible and return correct results.

This is my query:

```js
var sent_threads = GmailApp.search('in:sent after:2016/02/29');

  Logger.log(sent_threads.length); // This one prints 21

  for (var i = 0; i < sent_threads.length; i++) {

    var message = sent_threads[i].getMessages()[0];
    var recipient = message.getTo();
    Logger.log(recipient); // This one prints 21 email recipients

  }
```

But when I go to the Gmail.com and type in the query in search bar I will get 44 messages. Any idea why those results are different?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because the threads are collections of messages.

Try looping through the result of `getMessages()` instead of just accessing element `[0]`.