# Save Gmail attachments on Google Drive

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I would like to save gmail attachments(.pdf files) from a specific email in a specific Google Drive folder. I also need to rename file with a string composed by some string of the email.

I have developed a simple script using Google Apps Script with some functions.

This is the main function I have wrote:

```
function GmailToDrive() {
    var query = '';
    query = 'in:inbox from:noreply@agyo.io has:nouserlabels ';
    var threads = GmailApp.search(query);
    var label = getGmailLabel_(labelName);
    var parentFolder;
    if (threads.length > 0) {
        parentFolder = getFolder_(folderName);
    }
    var root = DriveApp.getRootFolder();
    for (var i in threads) {
        var mesgs = threads[i].getMessages();
        for (var j in mesgs) {
            //get attachments
            var attachments = mesgs[j].getAttachments();
            var message_body = mesgs[j].getBody();
            for (var k in attachments) {
                var attachment = attachments[k];
                var isDefinedType = checkIfDefinedType_(attachment);
                if (!isDefinedType) continue;
                var attachmentBlob = attachment.copyBlob();
                var file = DriveApp.createFile(attachmentBlob);
                file.setName(renameFile_(attachment, message_body))
                parentFolder.addFile(file);
                root.removeFile(file);
            }
        }
        threads[i].addLabel(label);
    }
}
```

The `checkIfDefinedType_(attachment)` function checks if the attachments is a .pdf file and the `renameFile_(attachment, message_body)` rename the attachment extracting some string from the email.

The script seems to be correctly developed but sometimes I have two or more same attachments saved in my google drive folder.

Comment: Welcome. "_but sometimes I have two or more same attachments saved in my google drive folder._" I do not understand what this means; would you please explain in more detail? Also, the code for `GmailToDrive` is pretty well known and reliable but I don't recall having seen the extra line of code `file.setName(renameFile_(attachment, message_body))`; would please provide the code for this function.

Comment: The script scans all Gmail items according to parameter of the query and has to save the attachment of no labeled mails to Google Drive. The script runs every 30 minutes and sometimes some attachments are saved more than one time in Google Drive folder.

Comment: ```file.setName``` is Google App Script function of Class File (https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file). The parameter of this function is a string obtained by the function ```renameFile_(attachment, message_body)``` that extract some string from the email text and concatenates them into a single string

Comment: "_sometimes some attachments are saved more than one time in Google Drive folder_". So what is the problem; that the code should look for duplicates and not process them twice? Perhaps even delete the duplicate?

Comment: The script processes all Gmail mails only if they have no user labels and save attachments. I can't understand why the script processes again labeled mails and so saves attachments again. we can consider "duplicate control" the label added to the mal after it's processed. Maybe I have put some conditions not in the right place...

Comment: _I can't understand why the script processes again labeled mails and so saves attachments again_ Without seeing your data, I suggest troubleshooting the initial value of "threads", this is likely to guide you in finetuning your query.

Comment: What do you mean with _I suggest troubleshooting the initial value of "threads"_?

Comment: I mean use an approach like show here [GMailApp Gmail search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35730107/) to loop through `threads` in order to see whether you can identify why you are getting duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

Stefano, I had the same issue, if this is the same code as adapted from [here](http://www.googleappsscript.org/home/fetch-gmail-attachment-to-google-drive-using-google-apps-script).
I removed the line `for (var i in fileTypesToExtract) {` which was causing duplicates for me. It was running the query for each of the file types.

Answer (score 0):

```
// `has:pdf` searches for messages with PDF attachments
var query = 'has:pdf in:inbox from:noreply@agyo.io has:nouserlabels '; 

var results = Gmail.Users.Messages.list(userId, {q: query});
results.messages.forEach(function (m) {
    var msg = GmailApp.getMessageById(m.id);
    msg.getAttachments().forEach(function (a) {
        var fileName = a.getName();
        fileName = saveAttachmentToFolder(folder, a, fileName, msg.getDate(), input.tz);
    });
});
function saveAttachmentToFolder(folder, attachment, fileName, date, timezone) {
    if (timezone) {
        fileName = standardizeName(attachment, date, timezone);
    }
    Logger.log(fileName);
    folder.createFile(attachment.copyBlob()).setName(fileName);
}
```

The code snippet above is based on a Gmail add-on that I created, specifically for saving attachments to labeled folders in Drive: https://github.com/ellaqezi/archiveByLabel/blob/main/Code.gs#L24

In the `label` field, you can define nested directories to create in Drive e.g. foo/bar.

In the `query` field, you can copy the parameters as you would use them in Gmail's search bar.