# How to get only time from getDate() in Google Apps Script?

Tags: logging, google-apps-script, time, gmail

I am trying to create a time based filter in Google Apps Script to filter out mails from my gmail account during a specific time of the day everyday with a specific subject line and apply a label to those mails.
So far i have segregated the mails by subject line and now i want to further segregate them using time. This is my code so far :

```
function xyz_filter() {
  var sent_threads = GmailApp.search('subject:xyz');
  Logger.log(sent_threads.length);
  for (var i = 0; i < sent_threads.length; i++) {
    var message = sent_threads[i].getMessages()[0];
    var recipient = message.getDate();
    Logger.log(recipient);
  }
}
```

I am fairly new to Google Apps Script and i have been rummaging through *stackoverflow* in the last few hours for a similar use case.
My code is mainly taken from this link : [GMailApp Gmail search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35730107/gmailapp-gmail-search)

This is the output on log :

```
[19-06-28 11:39:54:989 IST] 219.0
[19-06-28 11:39:55:110 IST] Fri Jun 28 00:01:48 GMT+05:30 2019
[19-06-28 11:39:55:176 IST] Fri Jun 28 00:01:48 GMT+05:30 2019
[19-06-28 11:39:55:235 IST] Fri Jun 28 00:01:48 GMT+05:30 2019
[19-06-28 11:39:55:344 IST] Fri Jun 28 00:01:48 GMT+05:30 2019
[19-06-28 11:39:55:403 IST] Fri Jun 28 00:01:48 GMT+05:30 2019
[19-06-28 11:39:55:462 IST] Fri Jun 28 00:01:48 GMT+05:30 2019
[19-06-28 11:39:55:518 IST] Fri Jun 28 00:01:48 GMT+05:30 2019
[19-06-28 11:39:55:578 IST] Fri Jun 28 00:01:48 GMT+05:30 2019
[19-06-28 11:39:55:635 IST] Fri Jun 28 00:01:48 GMT+05:30 2019
[19-06-28 11:39:55:724 IST] Fri Jun 28 00:01:48 GMT+05:30 2019
[19-06-28 11:39:55:785 IST] Fri Jun 28 00:01:48 GMT+05:30 2019
[19-06-28 11:39:55:842 IST] Fri Jun 28 00:01:48 GMT+05:30 2019
[19-06-28 11:39:55:896 IST] Fri Jun 28 00:01:48 GMT+05:30 2019
[19-06-28 11:39:55:974 IST] Fri Jun 28 00:01:48 GMT+05:30 2019
[19-06-28 11:39:56:032 IST] Fri Jun 28 00:01:48 GMT+05:30 2019
[19-06-28 11:39:56:138 IST] Fri Jun 28 00:01:48 GMT+05:30 2019
[19-06-28 11:39:56:198 IST] Fri Jun 28 00:01:48 GMT+05:30 2019
[19-06-28 11:39:56:270 IST] Fri Jun 28 00:01:48 GMT+05:30 2019
[19-06-28 11:39:56:328 IST] Fri Jun 28 00:01:48 GMT+05:30 2019
[19-06-28 11:39:56:385 IST] Fri Jun 28 00:01:48 GMT+05:30 2019
[19-06-28 11:39:56:441 IST] Fri Jun 28 00:01:48 GMT+05:30 2019
[19-06-28 11:39:56:502 IST] Fri Jun 28 00:01:48 GMT+05:30 2019
[19-06-28 11:39:56:558 IST] Fri Jun 28 00:01:48 GMT+05:30 2019
[19-06-28 11:39:56:621 IST] Fri Jun 28 00:01:48 GMT+05:30 2019
[19-06-28 11:39:56:676 IST] Fri Jun 28 00:01:48 GMT+05:30 2019
[19-06-28 11:39:56:730 IST] Fri Jun 28 00:01:48 GMT+05:30 2019
[19-06-28 11:39:56:786 IST] Fri Jun 28 00:01:48 GMT+05:30 2019
[19-06-28 11:39:56:841 IST] Fri Jun 28 00:01:48 GMT+05:30 2019
[19-06-28 11:39:56:898 IST] Fri Jun 28 00:01:48 GMT+05:30 2019
[19-06-28 11:39:56:956 IST] Fri Jun 28 00:01:45 GMT+05:30 2019
[19-06-28 11:39:57:011 IST] Fri Jun 28 00:01:45 GMT+05:30 2019
[19-06-28 11:39:57:066 IST] Fri Jun 28 00:01:45 GMT+05:30 2019
[19-06-28 11:39:57:123 IST] Fri Jun 28 00:01:45 GMT+05:30 2019
[19-06-28 11:39:57:180 IST] Fri Jun 28 00:01:43 GMT+05:30 2019
[19-06-28 11:39:57:237 IST] Fri Jun 28 00:01:45 GMT+05:30 2019
[19-06-28 11:39:57:297 IST] Fri Jun 28 00:01:43 GMT+05:30 2019
[19-06-28 11:39:57:353 IST] Fri Jun 28 00:01:43 GMT+05:30 2019
[19-06-28 11:39:57:514 IST] Fri Jun 28 00:01:41 GMT+05:30 2019
[19-06-28 11:39:57:569 IST] Fri Jun 28 00:01:43 GMT+05:30 2019
[19-06-28 11:39:57:625 IST] Fri Jun 28 00:01:41 GMT+05:30 2019
[19-06-28 11:39:57:681 IST] Fri Jun 28 00:01:43 GMT+05:30 2019
[19-06-28 11:39:57:736 IST] Fri Jun 28 00:01:43 GMT+05:30 2019
[19-06-28 11:39:57:793 IST] Fri Jun 28 00:01:43 GMT+05:30 2019
[19-06-28 11:39:57:848 IST] Fri Jun 28 00:01:43 GMT+05:30 2019
[19-06-28 11:39:57:978 IST] Fri Jun 28 00:01:41 GMT+05:30 2019
[19-06-28 11:39:58:069 IST] Fri Jun 28 00:01:39 GMT+05:30 2019
[19-06-28 11:39:58:124 IST] Fri Jun 28 00:01:40 GMT+05:30 2019
[19-06-28 11:39:58:180 IST] Fri Jun 28 00:01:40 GMT+05:30 2019
[19-06-28 11:39:58:236 IST] Fri Jun 28 00:01:39 GMT+05:30 2019
[19-06-28 11:39:58:293 IST] Fri Jun 28 00:01:39 GMT+05:30 2019
[19-06-28 11:39:58:349 IST] Fri Jun 28 00:01:38 GMT+05:30 2019
[19-06-28 11:39:58:404 IST] Fri Jun 28 00:01:38 GMT+05:30 2019
[19-06-28 11:39:58:459 IST] Fri Jun 28 00:01:36 GMT+05:30 2019
[19-06-28 11:39:58:521 IST] Fri Jun 28 00:01:36 GMT+05:30 2019
[19-06-28 11:39:58:580 IST] Fri Jun 28 00:01:36 GMT+05:30 2019
[19-06-28 11:39:58:634 IST] Fri Jun 28 00:01:25 GMT+05:30 2019
[19-06-28 11:39:58:689 IST] Fri Jun 28 00:01:26 GMT+05:30 2019
[19-06-28 11:39:58:744 IST] Fri Jun 28 00:01:26 GMT+05:30 2019
[19-06-28 11:39:58:799 IST] Fri Jun 28 00:01:26 GMT+05:30 2019
[19-06-28 11:39:58:857 IST] Fri Jun 28 00:01:27 GMT+05:30 2019
[19-06-28 11:39:58:913 IST] Fri Jun 28 00:01:26 GMT+05:30 2019
[19-06-28 11:39:58:969 IST] Fri Jun 28 00:01:26 GMT+05:30 2019
[19-06-28 11:39:59:027 IST] Fri Jun 28 00:01:26 GMT+05:30 2019
[19-06-28 11:39:59:082 IST] Fri Jun 28 00:01:25 GMT+05:30 2019
[19-06-28 11:39:59:147 IST] Fri Jun 28 00:01:25 GMT+05:30 2019
[19-06-28 11:39:59:203 IST] Fri Jun 28 00:01:25 GMT+05:30 2019
[19-06-28 11:39:59:258 IST] Fri Jun 28 00:01:23 GMT+05:30 2019
[19-06-28 11:39:59:314 IST] Fri Jun 28 00:01:25 GMT+05:30 2019
[19-06-28 11:39:59:368 IST] Fri Jun 28 00:01:23 GMT+05:30 2019
[19-06-28 11:39:59:424 IST] Fri Jun 28 00:01:22 GMT+05:30 2019
[19-06-28 11:39:59:481 IST] Fri Jun 28 00:01:22 GMT+05:30 2019
[19-06-28 11:39:59:536 IST] Fri Jun 28 00:01:21 GMT+05:30 2019
[19-06-28 11:39:59:642 IST] Fri Jun 28 00:01:14 GMT+05:30 2019
[19-06-28 11:39:59:698 IST] Fri Jun 28 00:01:14 GMT+05:30 2019
[19-06-28 11:39:59:755 IST] Fri Jun 28 00:01:18 GMT+05:30 2019
[19-06-28 11:39:59:819 IST] Fri Jun 28 00:01:14 GMT+05:30 2019
[19-06-28 11:39:59:877 IST] Fri Jun 28 00:01:12 GMT+05:30 2019
[19-06-28 11:39:59:933 IST] Fri Jun 28 00:01:12 GMT+05:30 2019
[19-06-28 11:39:59:988 IST] Fri Jun 28 00:01:05 GMT+05:30 2019
[19-06-28 11:40:00:053 IST] Fri Jun 28 00:01:05 GMT+05:30 2019
[19-06-28 11:40:00:112 IST] Fri Jun 28 00:01:04 GMT+05:30 2019
[19-06-28 11:40:00:170 IST] Fri Jun 28 00:01:00 GMT+05:30 2019
[19-06-28 11:40:00:226 IST] Fri Jun 28 00:01:00 GMT+05:30 2019
[19-06-28 11:40:00:280 IST] Fri Jun 28 00:01:00 GMT+05:30 2019
[19-06-28 11:40:00:351 IST] Fri Jun 28 00:00:57 GMT+05:30 2019
[19-06-28 11:40:00:407 IST] Fri Jun 28 00:00:58 GMT+05:30 2019
[19-06-28 11:40:00:464 IST] Fri Jun 28 00:00:57 GMT+05:30 2019
[19-06-28 11:40:00:520 IST] Fri Jun 28 00:00:56 GMT+05:30 2019
[19-06-28 11:40:00:577 IST] Fri Jun 28 00:00:56 GMT+05:30 2019
[19-06-28 11:40:00:664 IST] Fri Jun 28 00:00:56 GMT+05:30 2019
[19-06-28 11:40:00:762 IST] Fri Jun 28 00:00:56 GMT+05:30 2019
[19-06-28 11:40:00:819 IST] Fri Jun 28 00:00:56 GMT+05:30 2019
[19-06-28 11:40:00:878 IST] Fri Jun 28 00:00:55 GMT+05:30 2019
[19-06-28 11:40:00:938 IST] Fri Jun 28 00:00:56 GMT+05:30 2019
[19-06-28 11:40:00:998 IST] Fri Jun 28 00:00:55 GMT+05:30 2019
[19-06-28 11:40:01:059 IST] Fri Jun 28 00:00:55 GMT+05:30 2019
[19-06-28 11:40:01:276 IST] Fri Jun 28 00:00:55 GMT+05:30 2019
[19-06-28 11:40:01:333 IST] Fri Jun 28 00:00:55 GMT+05:30 2019
[19-06-28 11:40:01:391 IST] Fri Jun 28 00:00:53 GMT+05:30 2019
[19-06-28 11:40:01:477 IST] Fri Jun 28 00:00:53 GMT+05:30 2019
[19-06-28 11:40:01:578 IST] Fri Jun 28 00:00:52 GMT+05:30 2019
[19-06-28 11:40:01:654 IST] Fri Jun 28 00:00:52 GMT+05:30 2019
[19-06-28 11:40:01:717 IST] Fri Jun 28 00:00:50 GMT+05:30 2019
[19-06-28 11:40:01:774 IST] Fri Jun 28 00:00:50 GMT+05:30 2019
[19-06-28 11:40:01:832 IST] Fri Jun 28 00:00:51 GMT+05:30 2019
[19-06-28 11:40:01:887 IST] Fri Jun 28 00:00:50 GMT+05:30 2019
[19-06-28 11:40:01:943 IST] Fri Jun 28 00:00:51 GMT+05:30 2019
[19-06-28 11:40:02:030 IST] Fri Jun 28 00:00:51 GMT+05:30 2019
[19-06-28 11:40:02:087 IST] Fri Jun 28 00:00:49 GMT+05:30 2019
[19-06-28 11:40:02:145 IST] Fri Jun 28 00:00:46 GMT+05:30 2019
[19-06-28 11:40:02:202 IST] Fri Jun 28 00:00:47 GMT+05:30 2019
[19-06-28 11:40:02:261 IST] Fri Jun 28 00:00:48 GMT+05:30 2019
[19-06-28 11:40:02:321 IST] Fri Jun 28 00:00:47 GMT+05:30 2019
[19-06-28 11:40:02:377 IST] Fri Jun 28 00:00:46 GMT+05:30 2019
[19-06-28 11:40:02:437 IST] Fri Jun 28 00:00:47 GMT+05:30 2019
[19-06-28 11:40:02:494 IST] Fri Jun 28 00:00:46 GMT+05:30 2019
[19-06-28 11:40:02:551 IST] Fri Jun 28 00:00:46 GMT+05:30 2019
[19-06-28 11:40:02:608 IST] Fri Jun 28 00:00:45 GMT+05:30 2019
[19-06-28 11:40:02:664 IST] Fri Jun 28 00:00:40 GMT+05:30 2019
[19-06-28 11:40:02:735 IST] Thu Jun 27 00:02:22 GMT+05:30 2019
[19-06-28 11:40:02:804 IST] Thu Jun 27 00:02:25 GMT+05:30 2019
[19-06-28 11:40:02:878 IST] Thu Jun 27 00:02:25 GMT+05:30 2019
[19-06-28 11:40:02:939 IST] Thu Jun 27 00:02:26 GMT+05:30 2019
[19-06-28 11:40:02:996 IST] Thu Jun 27 00:02:24 GMT+05:30 2019
[19-06-28 11:40:03:089 IST] Thu Jun 27 00:02:24 GMT+05:30 2019
[19-06-28 11:40:03:167 IST] Thu Jun 27 00:02:24 GMT+05:30 2019
[19-06-28 11:40:03:235 IST] Thu Jun 27 00:02:24 GMT+05:30 2019
[19-06-28 11:40:03:292 IST] Thu Jun 27 00:02:24 GMT+05:30 2019
[19-06-28 11:40:03:348 IST] Thu Jun 27 00:02:24 GMT+05:30 2019
[19-06-28 11:40:03:403 IST] Thu Jun 27 00:02:24 GMT+05:30 2019
[19-06-28 11:40:03:469 IST] Thu Jun 27 00:02:23 GMT+05:30 2019
[19-06-28 11:40:03:528 IST] Thu Jun 27 00:02:23 GMT+05:30 2019
[19-06-28 11:40:03:584 IST] Thu Jun 27 00:02:23 GMT+05:30 2019
[19-06-28 11:40:03:644 IST] Thu Jun 27 00:02:24 GMT+05:30 2019
[19-06-28 11:40:03:715 IST] Thu Jun 27 00:02:24 GMT+05:30 2019
[19-06-28 11:40:03:780 IST] Thu Jun 27 00:02:24 GMT+05:30 2019
[19-06-28 11:40:03:966 IST] Thu Jun 27 00:02:23 GMT+05:30 2019
[19-06-28 11:40:04:023 IST] Thu Jun 27 00:02:23 GMT+05:30 2019
[19-06-28 11:40:04:081 IST] Thu Jun 27 00:02:23 GMT+05:30 2019
[19-06-28 11:40:04:160 IST] Thu Jun 27 00:02:23 GMT+05:30 2019
[19-06-28 11:40:04:216 IST] Thu Jun 27 00:02:22 GMT+05:30 2019
[19-06-28 11:40:04:271 IST] Thu Jun 27 00:02:20 GMT+05:30 2019
[19-06-28 11:40:04:330 IST] Thu Jun 27 00:02:22 GMT+05:30 2019
[19-06-28 11:40:04:410 IST] Thu Jun 27 00:02:22 GMT+05:30 2019
[19-06-28 11:40:04:623 IST] Thu Jun 27 00:02:22 GMT+05:30 2019
[19-06-28 11:40:04:684 IST] Thu Jun 27 00:02:22 GMT+05:30 2019
[19-06-28 11:40:04:742 IST] Thu Jun 27 00:02:22 GMT+05:30 2019
[19-06-28 11:40:04:799 IST] Thu Jun 27 00:02:21 GMT+05:30 2019
[19-06-28 11:40:04:871 IST] Thu Jun 27 00:02:21 GMT+05:30 2019
[19-06-28 11:40:04:929 IST] Thu Jun 27 00:02:21 GMT+05:30 2019
[19-06-28 11:40:05:054 IST] Thu Jun 27 00:02:21 GMT+05:30 2019
[19-06-28 11:40:05:110 IST] Thu Jun 27 00:02:21 GMT+05:30 2019
[19-06-28 11:40:05:168 IST] Thu Jun 27 00:02:21 GMT+05:30 2019
[19-06-28 11:40:05:223 IST] Thu Jun 27 00:02:20 GMT+05:30 2019
[19-06-28 11:40:05:281 IST] Thu Jun 27 00:02:20 GMT+05:30 2019
[19-06-28 11:40:05:335 IST] Thu Jun 27 00:02:20 GMT+05:30 2019
[19-06-28 11:40:05:393 IST] Thu Jun 27 00:02:20 GMT+05:30 2019
[19-06-28 11:40:05:452 IST] Thu Jun 27 00:02:21 GMT+05:30 2019
[19-06-28 11:40:05:511 IST] Thu Jun 27 00:02:21 GMT+05:30 2019
[19-06-28 11:40:05:566 IST] Thu Jun 27 00:02:21 GMT+05:30 2019
[19-06-28 11:40:05:624 IST] Thu Jun 27 00:02:21 GMT+05:30 2019
[19-06-28 11:40:05:680 IST] Thu Jun 27 00:02:21 GMT+05:30 2019
[19-06-28 11:40:05:740 IST] Thu Jun 27 00:02:20 GMT+05:30 2019
[19-06-28 11:40:05:798 IST] Thu Jun 27 00:02:20 GMT+05:30 2019
[19-06-28 11:40:05:867 IST] Thu Jun 27 00:02:20 GMT+05:30 2019
[19-06-28 11:40:05:939 IST] Thu Jun 27 00:02:20 GMT+05:30 2019
[19-06-28 11:40:05:994 IST] Thu Jun 27 00:02:20 GMT+05:30 2019
[19-06-28 11:40:06:051 IST] Thu Jun 27 00:02:20 GMT+05:30 2019
[19-06-28 11:40:06:108 IST] Thu Jun 27 00:02:20 GMT+05:30 2019
[19-06-28 11:40:06:165 IST] Thu Jun 27 00:02:20 GMT+05:30 2019
[19-06-28 11:40:06:319 IST] Thu Jun 27 00:02:20 GMT+05:30 2019
[19-06-28 11:40:06:379 IST] Thu Jun 27 00:02:20 GMT+05:30 2019
[19-06-28 11:40:06:569 IST] Thu Jun 27 00:02:19 GMT+05:30 2019
[19-06-28 11:40:06:624 IST] Thu Jun 27 00:02:19 GMT+05:30 2019
[19-06-28 11:40:06:684 IST] Thu Jun 27 00:02:19 GMT+05:30 2019
[19-06-28 11:40:06:740 IST] Thu Jun 27 00:02:19 GMT+05:30 2019
[19-06-28 11:40:06:800 IST] Thu Jun 27 00:02:19 GMT+05:30 2019
[19-06-28 11:40:06:861 IST] Thu Jun 27 00:02:19 GMT+05:30 2019
[19-06-28 11:40:06:917 IST] Thu Jun 27 00:02:19 GMT+05:30 2019
[19-06-28 11:40:06:972 IST] Thu Jun 27 00:02:19 GMT+05:30 2019
[19-06-28 11:40:07:029 IST] Thu Jun 27 00:02:19 GMT+05:30 2019
[19-06-28 11:40:07:084 IST] Thu Jun 27 00:02:19 GMT+05:30 2019
[19-06-28 11:40:07:143 IST] Thu Jun 27 00:02:19 GMT+05:30 2019
[19-06-28 11:40:07:199 IST] Thu Jun 27 00:02:19 GMT+05:30 2019
[19-06-28 11:40:07:254 IST] Thu Jun 27 00:02:18 GMT+05:30 2019
[19-06-28 11:40:07:311 IST] Thu Jun 27 00:02:19 GMT+05:30 2019
[19-06-28 11:40:07:370 IST] Thu Jun 27 00:02:18 GMT+05:30 2019
[19-06-28 11:40:07:426 IST] Thu Jun 27 00:02:19 GMT+05:30 2019
[19-06-28 11:40:07:489 IST] Thu Jun 27 00:02:18 GMT+05:30 2019
[19-06-28 11:40:07:547 IST] Thu Jun 27 00:02:17 GMT+05:30 2019
[19-06-28 11:40:07:779 IST] Thu Jun 27 00:02:18 GMT+05:30 2019
[19-06-28 11:40:07:834 IST] Thu Jun 27 00:02:17 GMT+05:30 2019
[19-06-28 11:40:07:906 IST] Thu Jun 27 00:02:18 GMT+05:30 2019
[19-06-28 11:40:07:977 IST] Thu Jun 27 00:02:18 GMT+05:30 2019
[19-06-28 11:40:08:039 IST] Thu Jun 27 00:02:16 GMT+05:30 2019
[19-06-28 11:40:08:099 IST] Thu Jun 27 00:02:17 GMT+05:30 2019
[19-06-28 11:40:08:165 IST] Thu Jun 27 00:02:17 GMT+05:30 2019
[19-06-28 11:40:08:222 IST] Thu Jun 27 00:02:17 GMT+05:30 2019
[19-06-28 11:40:08:277 IST] Thu Jun 27 00:02:17 GMT+05:30 2019
[19-06-28 11:40:08:330 IST] Thu Jun 27 00:02:17 GMT+05:30 2019
[19-06-28 11:40:08:390 IST] Thu Jun 27 00:02:16 GMT+05:30 2019
[19-06-28 11:40:08:446 IST] Thu Jun 27 00:02:16 GMT+05:30 2019
[19-06-28 11:40:08:611 IST] Thu Jun 27 00:02:16 GMT+05:30 2019
[19-06-28 11:40:08:685 IST] Thu Jun 27 00:02:16 GMT+05:30 2019
[19-06-28 11:40:08:745 IST] Thu Jun 27 00:02:14 GMT+05:30 2019
[19-06-28 11:40:08:806 IST] Thu Jun 27 00:02:14 GMT+05:30 2019
[19-06-28 11:40:08:993 IST] Thu Jun 27 00:02:14 GMT+05:30 2019
[19-06-28 11:40:09:051 IST] Thu Jun 27 00:02:14 GMT+05:30 2019
[19-06-28 11:40:09:107 IST] Thu Jun 27 00:02:14 GMT+05:30 2019
[19-06-28 11:40:09:164 IST] Thu Jun 27 00:02:14 GMT+05:30 2019
[19-06-28 11:40:09:252 IST] Thu Jun 27 00:02:14 GMT+05:30 2019
[19-06-28 11:40:09:309 IST] Thu Jun 27 00:02:14 GMT+05:30 2019
[19-06-28 11:40:09:470 IST] Thu Jun 27 00:02:14 GMT+05:30 2019
[19-06-28 11:40:09:529 IST] Thu Jun 27 00:02:14 GMT+05:30 2019
[19-06-28 11:40:09:588 IST] Thu Jun 27 00:02:14 GMT+05:30 2019
[19-06-28 11:40:09:739 IST] Thu Jun 27 00:02:14 GMT+05:30 2019
[19-06-28 11:40:09:795 IST] Thu Jun 27 00:02:08 GMT+05:30 2019
[19-06-28 11:40:09:856 IST] Thu Jun 27 00:02:08 GMT+05:30 2019
[19-06-28 11:40:09:912 IST] Thu Jun 27 00:02:08 GMT+05:30 2019
```

Please suggest a method to get only time from this output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you tried to use: `recipient.getHours(); recipient.getMinutes(); recipient.getSeconds();` this will take hours, minutes and seconds from recipient.

Here you will find more information about how to use it https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date. I hope that helps, greetings.

Comment: Thanks. It is working. I don't understand why they didn't add such basic information here : https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/

Answer (score 0):

Try :recipient.toTimeString() this will give you as "00:01:48 GMT+05:30" and below code will help to get only time  like "00:01:48"

```
function CreatTimestring(str1,pos){
    var str2='';
    for (var i=0;i<pos-1;i++){
      str2+=str1[i];
    }
    return str2;
  }
TimeStr = CreatTimestring(recipient.toTimeString(),recipient.toTimeString().indexOf('G',0));
```

Hope this will help others..

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).